# Finding length of fiber

Tags: physics

[image]

It should be right. I did $\dfrac{V}{\pi r^2} \rightarrow \dfrac{0.5722}{3.14\cdot 3.6^2} = 0.01406090272863$. What's the problem?

Comment: I don't know how you calculated $V$, but [here's](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(69.08+g)%2F((19.32+g%2Fcm%5E3)*(pi*(3.6+micrometers)%5E2))) what I get.

Comment: How did you come up with $0.5722$? I don't see it being a multiple of the actual volume up to any power of $10$.

Comment: I followed the steps in the book for a similar problem  -http://i.imgur.com/skHEnMy.png Was the book wrong?